# strcat vs strncat for string literal

Tags: c, string, compiler-construction, concatenation

I want to append a string literal to destination. I can use `strcat` or `strncat`:

```
strcat(dest, "values");
```

Or

```
strncat(dest, "values", sizeof("values") - 1);
```

`strcat` has shorter code, it looks neat.

But I wonder about their runtime performance.

Is `strncat` slightly faster at runtime because there's no need to locate terminator?

Or maybe compilers could do optimization and so there is no difference?

Comment: Either way, the null terminator for `dest` needs to be found.  And either way, the code needs to iterate over all the characters in `"values"`.  So it makes no difference.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I thought `strncat` reads up to the byte `s`, and `strcat` reads one more byte, the null terminator. I was wrong from the beginning?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - `strncat` will enable the programmer to prevent buffer overruns. `strcat` does not have this luxury

Comment: @EdHeal: Indeed.  I was merely commenting on the premise that one would be faster than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, both `strcat` and `strncat` loks for the null terminator, the difference is that `strncat` also check for the size of the copied data, and will copy only `n` bytes.

Second, since `strcat` does not check for the size of the copied data, and copies until it gets to a null terminator, it might (and will!!) cause a buffer overflow, overriding data that is stored in memory after the buffer you copy to.

Third, your usage of the strncat is not safer, as you limit the copy by the size of the source buffer, not the destination buffer. E.g. to use it correctly you should pass the size of the destination buffer:

```
strncat(dest, "values", sizeof(dest) -1 );
```

Fourth, if the size of the source string is bigger than than `n` of the destination, a null terminator will not be appended, so after the call to `strncat` you should add it yourself:

```
strncat(dest, "values", sizeof(dest) -1 );
dest[sizeof(dest) - 1] = '\0';
```

Last thing, since this is strncat, and it copies to  wherever the destination string terminates, the size calculation is slightly more complex and is actually:

```
strncat(dest, "values", total_size_of_dest_buffer - strlen(dest) - 1 );
```

Comment: 1) `strncat(dest, "values", sizeof(dest) -1 );` is incorrect.  Could use `strncat(dest, "values", sizeof(dest) - strlen(dest) - 1);` 2) "if the size of the source string is bigger than than n of the destination, a null terminator will not be appended, " and the following `strncat()` is also amiss. `strncat()` always null character terminates.

Answer (score 1):

1. I am absolutely sure, that performance is not an issue here.
2. If you take a look at sources of both functions [`strcpy()`](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/string/strcpy.c) and [`strncpy()`](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/string/strncpy.c) (from glibc) you'll find out that both of them need to iterate over each character of `src` argument.
3. Use `strcpy()` as it's much easier to read and maintain, and is less error-prone.

Also, if there is anything that could optimize this code, I guess any decent compiler will handle that, as it seems to be quite common expression.

Comment: Reading the sources is indeed the right thing. I should have done it. Thank you for that. Though you have typos of function names.

Comment: Ops... I've fixed those typos. ;)

Comment: If the usage is as shown by OP i.e. putting strlen as second argument, then indeed strcat is less error prone. But the correct way to use strncpy is to put remaining buffer space as second argument, as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `strncat` slightly faster at runtime because there's no need to locate terminator?

```
char *strncat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n);
```

Unlikely.  In general, `char *strncat()` needs to locate a *null character* in `s2`, if it exists before `s2[n]`, as concatenation stop before `n` characters.  Of course, the 
*null character* in `s2`  of `strcpy(s1,s2)` needs to be found.

`strncat(dest, "values", sizeof("values") - 1);` may be *slower* than `strcat(dest, "values");` and is not *safer*.

Code that does not overrun the array that may truncate:

```
// Assuming dest is an array
strncat(dest, "values", sizeof dest - strlen(dest) - 1);
```

---

An optimization compiler is allowed to "look-inside" well known functions like the ones below and emit code that "knows" the length/size of "values".  such a compiler would certainly make equivalent performance code for the 2 below as the resultant functionality is identical - in this case.

```
strcat(dest, "values");
// or
strncat(dest, "values", sizeof("values") - 1);
```